# Need code to only run when 'other' option is selected | Javascript / swig

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, swig-template

I want to use swig (it is my templating engine) to insert JavaScript so that the following shows only when the select option 'other' is chosen.

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <select class="custom-select">
  <option selected>Select Switch Manufacturer</option>
  <option value="cisco">Cisco</option>
  <option value="netgear">NetGear</option>
  <option value="d-link">D-link</option>
  <option value="tp-link">TP-link</option>
  <option value="hewlett-packard">Hewlett-Packard</option>
  <option value="linksys">Linksys</option>
  <option value="allied">Allied</option>
  <option value="brocade">Brocade</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
 </select>
```

This is the code I want to only show when the user selects the 'other' option in the code above. How can I do this with Javascript / swig?

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="switch-manufacturer" placeholder="Switch Manufacturer">
</div> <!-- Switch Manufacturer other input only show when above 'other' is selected -->
```

Comment: Do you have any client side javascript?  WHat is the event (onClick) handler?  What framework / libraries are you using?

Comment: I am using Node.js with express and swig. No client side javascript yet other than basic dashboard stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I made a pen for you.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZENjo

You just need to use the `value` property of the `<select>` element.

I used a button to call the function, you can use whatever you want, including adding an `onclick` to the `<select>` element, which would look something like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select class="custom-select" id="sel" onclick="foo()">
  <option selected>Select Switch Manufacturer</option>
  <option value="cisco">Cisco</option>
  <option value="netgear">NetGear</option>
  <option value="d-link">D-link</option>
  <option value="tp-link">TP-link</option>
  <option value="hewlett-packard">Hewlett-Packard</option>
  <option value="linksys">Linksys</option>
  <option value="allied">Allied</option>
  <option value="brocade">Brocade</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I tried to follow that pen and came up with this but it doesn't seem to work

`<div class="form-group">
<select class="custom-select">
 <option selected>Select Switch Manufacturer</option>
<option value="other" onclick="manAdd()">Other</option>
</select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="">
 function manAdd(){
 var sel=document.getElementById('manAdd');
 if(sel.value=='other'){
 sel.innerHTML('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="switch-manufacturer" placeholder="Switch Manufacturer">');
 }
}
</script>
<div class="form-group" id="manAdd">
 </div>`

Comment: You cannot set an `onclick` on an `option` element, only `select`. Additionally, you cannot place any other element inside an `option` element. You would have to use an alternative, such as a different type of drop-down menu, or place the element outside the `option` element. I give you the second option in this pen 
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzjpVJ

Comment: If you absolutely must have the textbox inside the dropdown list, there are several frameworks that let you do that.

Comment: thanks i got it to work. I figured out the issue was what you said, I also realized I was trying to place the textarea in the drop down and moved it outside into its own div. That seemed to work. Thank you for the help you set me in the right direction.